# Change single TYPO3 fluid template

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid

Will there be a feature I don't know for TYPO3 fluid templates?

For some extensions (e.g. powermail, news) there are many templates for functions I don't use. But if I want to adapt a single template, all of them have to be copied. Will be there an alternative way where I can set a single template path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible by the means of the FLUID core.

However, there is the extension [view](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/view) that allows to do exactly what you want, and a [feature request](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/49343) to move that functionality to the FLUID core.

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 v6.2 it is possible to add multiple template, layout and partial paths. Simply use something like this.

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    view {
        templateRootPath >
        templateRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates
            20 = fileadmin/templates/myextension/Templates
        }

        partialRootPath >
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Partials
            20 = fileadmin/templates/myextension/Partials
        }
    }
}
```

**Remember**: The extension is starting to search for the file beginning with the highest number and ends with the lowest, where you should add the extensions default path.

Answer (score 1):

Current syntax: add the following to your own extension's constants file and load it after Powermail's own. The same syntax applies to `partialRootPath` and `layoutRootPath`.

You only need to copy the individual file you want to customize - respecting the original folder structure - and not the entire folder. TYPO3 will search for the file in all of the paths indicated in the `...rootPaths` array, starting with the highest-numbered entry.

By using the singular form `...rootPath` and not `...rootPaths`, your definition will be appended to the generated ...`rootPaths` array. Therefore, adding the following to your constants…

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates
    }
}
```

…will generate…

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:powermail/Resources/Private/Partials/
            1 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... Just copy whole folder into for an example `fileadmin/ext/powermail` (also with partials!) and then change the paths in the extension's TS constants .

To make it working on the single files developers should implement such behavior directly in their extensions, but it would be quite uncomfortable solution (for developers and for users as well)